# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'StoreChannel'

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to accommodate slash commands in a discord bot I'm working on and I'm using the discord-ui package for this. I would just like to get some advice on this error and how to fix it

**AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'StoreChannel'**

The code is

```
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_ui import UI, SlashOption

client = commands.Bot(" ")
ui = UI(client)

@ui.slash.command("hello_world", options=[SlashOption(bool, "cool", "whether this libary is cool", required=False)])
async def command(ctx, cool=True):
    await ctx.respond("You said this libary is " + str(cool))
```

for more details on the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/./Bot1/main.py", line 4, in <module>
from discord_ui import UI, SlashOption
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
from .client import *
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/client.py", line 1, in <module>
from .cogs import BaseCallable, InteractionableCog, ListeningComponent
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/cogs.py", line 5, in <module>
from .slash.types import BaseCommand, ContextCommand, MessageCommand, SlashCommand, SlashSubcommand, UserCommand
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/slash/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from . import ext
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/slash/ext/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .builder import *
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/slash/ext/builder.py", line 2, in <module>
from ...enums import CommandType, OptionType
File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_ui/enums.py", line 13, in <module>
discord.StoreChannel,
```

Comment: With discord.py 2.0 I'm not sure why any other packages are needed.

Comment: I was trying to implement slash commands and idk if discord py can handle it since it got discontinued

Comment: It looks like the package you're trying to use is trying to import `StoreChannel`, which no longer exists as of discord.py 2.0. You should just use discord.py by itself.